# Word VBA : Search String Then Do in Case

Tags: vba, ms-word

Well, it will be very helpful to me if you just try to help me on this, it's for my internship and it's very important to me. Im working with this tool to sort some 'products properties'. I need to search the type of the 'Article', Then when the specific 'Article' is found, i'll add a footnote. **I Did this like here below**

```
Sub Find()'There is many other Calls but lets take those for example
   Call SearchAndMark("Article : KR", "arKR")
   Call SearchAndMark("Article : IP", "arIP")
   Call SearchAndMark("Article : IA", "arIA")
   Call SearchAndMark("Article : 12", "ar12000") 
End Sub
```

*This is my function SearchAndMark*

```
Sub SearchAndMark(searchString As String, markText As String)
Dim CurrentPage As Integer
Dim LastPage As Integer

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
LastPage = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

While (CurrentPage < LastPage)
    Selection.Find.Forward = True
    Selection.Find.Text = searchString
    Selection.Find.Execute

    If Selection.Find.Found Then
        CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        Debug.Print "Found on Page " & CurrentPage
        Call ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add(Selection.range, "", markText)
    Else
    CurrentPage = LastPage
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

**NOW, My problem, and what i need?**
Well, the other pages which contains description of non researched Articles, with unknown names, i need also to add another same footnote or a tag in the end of all their pages.
**Another idea :**
I tried to write at the end of all the pages a same tag, then when researching my 'searchString' i tag a new one and delete the old. *But i didnt get a result, the execution runs wrongly !! Maybe because of the function 'Selection.Find' which will lost the way.*

**IF you have a question just tell me. Thanks for being helpful**

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a dictionary to keep track of whether each page has had a footnote added. At the end of your code you then read through the dictionary to find those pages not yet marked and then do something to them.

To use early binding with the `Scripting.Dictionary` object, from the VBA IDE, select the Tools menu, then References. Find the entry for "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" and check the box.

At the start of your code, call a function to create the dictionary with an entry for each page and the value `False` to show that no footnotes have been added. In your later code, when you add a footnote you also change the value in the dictionary for that page.

Here's the code.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Find() 'There is many other Calls but lets take those for example

Dim dictOfPages As Scripting.Dictionary

    Set dictOfPages = BuildDict()

   Call SearchAndMark("Article : KR", "arKR", dictOfPages)
   Call SearchAndMark("Article : IP", "arIP", dictOfPages)
   Call SearchAndMark("Article : IA", "arIA", dictOfPages)
   Call SearchAndMark("Article : 12", "ar12000", dictOfPages)

   Call MarkRemainingPages(dictOfPages)

End Sub

Sub SearchAndMark(searchString As String, markText As String, ByRef dictOfPages As Scripting.Dictionary)
Dim CurrentPage As Integer
Dim LastPage As Integer

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
LastPage = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

While (CurrentPage < LastPage)
    Selection.Find.Forward = True
    Selection.Find.Text = searchString
    Selection.Find.Execute

    If Selection.Find.Found Then
        CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        Debug.Print "Found on Page " & CurrentPage
        dictOfPages.item(CurrentPage) = True
        Call ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add(Selection.Range, "", markText)
    Else
    CurrentPage = LastPage
    End If
Wend
End Sub

Private Function BuildDict() As Scripting.Dictionary

Dim theDict As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim i As Integer

    Set theDict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For i = 1 To Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)
        theDict.Add i, False
    Next i

    Set BuildDict = theDict

End Function

Private Sub MarkRemainingPages(ByRef dictOfPages As Scripting.Dictionary)

Dim pageNum As Variant

    For Each pageNum In dictOfPages.Keys
        If Not dictOfPages.Item(CInt(pageNum)) Then
            Debug.Print "Not found on page " & pageNum
            ' Do something here, add another footnote or text in the footer
        End If
    Next pageNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll show you how i've done below ! It's working like we want.

Answer (score 0):

**Hello everyone, Here's my final solution**, i just underlined all, the articles that i'm searching. Then, it becomes easy to find all the other non underlined. **Take a look below this.**

```
Sub Find()
Call SearchAndMark("Article : KR", "arKR") 
Call SearchAndMark("Article : IP", "arIP")
Call SearchAndMark("Article : IA", "arIA")
Call SearchAndMark("Article : 12", "ar12000")
End Sub


Sub SearchAndMark(searchString As String, markText As String)
Dim CurrentPage As Integer
Dim LastPage As Integer

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
LastPage = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

While (CurrentPage < LastPage)
    Selection.Find.Forward = True
    Selection.Find.Text = searchString
    Selection.Find.Execute

    If Selection.Find.Found Then
'Here i underline these names
        Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineSingle
        CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
        Debug.Print "Found on Page " & CurrentPage
        Call ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add(Selection.range, "", markText)
    Else
    CurrentPage = LastPage
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```

**After this, i added a new function to search the "Article : ^?" which are not underlined**

```
Sub underlineTXT()
Dim CurrentPage As Integer
Dim LastPage As Integer

Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToFirst
CurrentPage = Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
LastPage = Selection.Information(wdNumberOfPagesInDocument)

While (CurrentPage < LastPage)
    Selection.Find.Forward = True
    Selection.Find.Text = "Article : ^?"
    Selection.Find.Execute

    If Selection.Font.Underline = wdUnderlineNone Then
    CurrentPage =Selection.Information(wdActiveEndAdjustedPageNumber)
    Call ActiveDocument.Footnotes.Add(Selection.range, "", "Défauts")
    Else
          Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToPage, Which:=wdGoToNext
    End If
 Wend
 End Sub
```

**That's all, And thanks to all for your precious contribution**